# Vercel redirect a deployment URL

Tags: web, url, redirect, web-applications, vercel

As we all know Vercel create a unique URL for each deployment.
But my problem is I need to edit files in that deployed URL, but every time I edit and push it creates new unique URL. I want to edit files on that particular URL.

I thought maybe redirecting would be a way but Vercel don't allows redirecting deployment URLs

I tried to use Vercel Redirection service.. Maybe aliases help?